# How to count data based on specific condition in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

Let's say I have a table of persons with ids and names as follows

```
[Person]
ID       NAME
================
1        Michael
2        Michelle
3        Emma
4        Evan
5        Ellen
6        Gary
```

I want to count the number of persons based on the first characters of their names.
Here's the output I expect

```
NUMBER_OF_PERSONS
=================
2 //M = Michael and Michelle
3 //E = Emma, Evan and Ellen
1 //G = Gary
```

How do I achieve this in Oracle?

And here's my query

```sql
select count(id) as number_of_person    
from person
where substr(name) in (select distinct substr(name,1,1) from person);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive that purpose using below solution.

```sql
with Person (ID, NAME ) as (
select 1, 'Michael'  from dual union all
select 2, 'Michelle' from dual union all
select 3, 'Emma'   from dual union all
select 4, 'Evan'   from dual union all
select 5, 'Ellen'  from dual union all
select 6, 'Gary' from dual
)
select count(*) || ' //' || substr(NAME, 1, 1) || ' = ' || 
  case 
    when regexp_count( listagg(NAME, ' and ') within group ( order by ID ), ' and ') > 1 
      then regexp_replace( listagg(NAME, ', ') within group ( order by ID ), ', ([^,]+)$', ' and \1 ', 1, 1 ) 
    else listagg(NAME, ' and ') within group ( order by ID )
  end  NUMBER_OF_PERSONS
from Person
group by substr(NAME, 1, 1)
order by substr(NAME, 1, 1)
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4a249cda93c49ef844e9e34fa80da438)

Comment: thankyou for your answer, and sorry for the late reply @MDO

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the count, you would use `group by`:

```
select substr(name, 1, 1) as first_letter,
       count(*) as number_of_person    
from person
group by substr(name, 1, 1) ;
```

If, in addition, you actually wanted the list of names, you could put that in another column, assuming there are not too many:

```
select substr(name, 1, 1) as first_letter,
       count(*) as number_of_person,
       listagg(name, ', ') within group (order by name) as names  
from person
group by substr(name, 1, 1) ;
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer, I think your solution might work :) @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to it:

```
WITH tbl AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Michael' AS NAME  FROM dual UNION
SELECT 2, 'Michelle' FROM dual UNION
SELECT 3, 'Emma'     FROM dual UNION
SELECT 4, 'Evan'     FROM dual UNION
SELECT 5, 'Ellen'    FROM dual UNION
SELECT 6, 'Gary'     FROM dual
)

SELECT COUNT(1)
     , SUBSTR(names.name,1,1)
     , REGEXP_REPLACE((listagg(names.name,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY names.name)), ',([^,]*)$', ' and \1')
  FROM tbl names
 GROUP BY SUBSTR(names.name,1,1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll look into it @Gnqz